# Node Js sqlResponse values are not read by JavaScript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

Hey There hope you all are fine from CORONA.
I have a little issue that i have a page on which all countries name are coming from the database and displaying on the page.

What i want, i want them to be clickable as a `<li> </li>` and by using the `AJAX` i want their country code to be displayed without using the `form`

I can't read the response of the node js sql by the Javascript/jQuery

**it is working with the form but i don't want to use form is there any kind of help will be appreciated**

[image]
[image]

```
 $("#Ul_id button").click(() => {
        console.log($(this).closest('button').val())
    }) //this response undefined
```

Comment: here no need to write `closest`, you are already in button element, change this `$(this).closest('button').val()` to `$(this).val()`

Comment: but this function is not reading the value of sqlResponse still.

Comment: What are you getting, please add error log or console here